# CSqlDataProvider Complex Query and totalItemCount

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a very complex query using `CSqlDataProvider` and I'm trying to get the pagination `totalItemCount` to work, but it's returning wrong count. I tried to create a second SQL just to COUNT items, but it's really hard, can anyone help me?

CSqlDataProvider Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

Controller Code:

```
    $dayofweek = date('w');     

    $sql = "( SELECT `profile`.`id` as profile_id, `profile`.`name` as profile_name, `events_reminder`.`id`,
                CASE WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
                    THEN 
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', event_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    ELSE
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', event_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    END as revent_datetime,
                CASE WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
                    THEN 
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', list_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    ELSE
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', list_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    END as rlist_datetime
                FROM events_reminder
                LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles` `profile` ON (`events_reminder`.`profile_id`=`profile`.`id`)
                HAVING revent_datetime NOT IN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM events WHERE `events`.`profile_id`=`events_reminder`.`profile_id`) )
            UNION ALL
            ( SELECT `profile`.`id` as profile_id, `profile`.`name` as profile_name, `events_reminder`.`id`,
                CASE WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
                    THEN 
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek + 7 DAY), ' ', event_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    ELSE
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday + 7 DAY), ' ', event_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    END as revent_datetime,
                CASE WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
                    THEN 
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek + 7 DAY), ' ', list_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    ELSE
                        DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday + 7 DAY), ' ', list_time ), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
                    END as rlist_datetime
                FROM events_reminder
                LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles` `profile` ON (`events_reminder`.`profile_id`=`profile`.`id`)
                HAVING revent_datetime NOT IN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM events WHERE `events`.`profile_id`=`events_reminder`.`profile_id`) )
                ORDER BY revent_datetime";

    $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What [`queryScalar`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail) does is:

> Executes the SQL statement and returns the value of the **first column in the first row of data**.

So to use it for getting `count` you will have to add a `count(*)` to your sql query, that too in the beginning of the query, like this:

```
SELECT count(*), `profile`.`id` as profile_id, `profile`.`name` ...
```

**Update:**

Since you are using `UNION` you have to move the `count(*)` outside, also give an alias:

```
SELECT count(*) from (((select ...) UNION ALL (select ...)) as alias)
```

For your exact situation you can do:

```
$count_sql='SELECT count(*) from (('. $sql .') as alias)';
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($count_sql)->queryScalar();
```

Comment: If I add the `count(*)` I get `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sp.events_reminder.profile_id' in 'where clause'.` =/

Comment: ok, i hadn't seen your union, try a select outside the union like: `select count(*) from ((select ...)UNION ALL(select ...))`.

Comment: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias.` Not worked too =/

Comment: I tried it `$sql_count = 'select count(*) from (' . $sql . ')'; `

Comment: use aliases for your derived table, i.e `from ((select ...) as alias1 union all (select ...) as alias2)` or move the alias outside : `from (((select)union all(select))as alias)`

Comment: I have updated answer, also added mysql tag to your question.